# How to build the right Command Value for writing it into Android BLE Characteristics

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to build an Android App with Bluetooth LE Communication Features.
Kotlin is used in Android Studio.
Gatt Services, Characteristics & Descriptors are discovered,
a Notification on CCCD ist set.

So far, no problem!

Now i need Help to send (write) the right **Command** to an Characteristic.

**This is what the Command should look like
/ Information from the manufacturer api:**

**General Command Format**

| B0 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | B6 | Bn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Preamble (0xAB) | Command ID (low byte) | Command ID (high byte) | Parameter Byte 0 | Parameter Byte 1 | Parameter Byte 2 | Parameter Byte 3 | Parameter Byte (n-3) |

The command ID is a two-byte (16bit) integer, the lower part occupies **B1**, the higher
part **B2**. The endianness used throughout the protocol is **little-endian**.

| Command name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| PCMD_API_GET_INFO | 0x01 |
| PCMD_ ... | 0x02 |
| ... | 0x03 |

What is the correct definition for the variable

```
val PCMD_API_GET_INFO = 0x01
```

that is used in the

```
.setValue(value: ????)
```

Function?

How is the Command ID made up/ how is it formed?

**Thank you in advance for your efforts & hopefully good answers**

Comment: Could you add the link to the manufacturer API?

Comment: Link to manufacturer API:
https://poollab.org/assets/website/download/wiki/BLE.pdf

Comment: Have you had a look at page 9 of the linked document? there is a table containing the values for the PCMD_API_GET_INFO command including the expected response

Comment: Yes, I saw the Command ID on page 9. It is defined there with the value 0x0001h - but I can only define this value as a String. Not as Int or ByteArray - unfortunately, I can't do it myself. Should a BLE device handle a string in this Context? I will try it this evening & give a feedback.

Comment: Unless I am missing something: [setValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic#setValue(kotlin.ByteArray)) accepts a byte array

Comment: So, tested: can not define the Value: 0x0001h as byteArrayOf() or to Int.
Send (write) to Device as String did not work too.

Comment: I think you need to add some code to your question, everything else would be just guessing

Answer (score 0):

This is the right Value/ Format to write it into Characteristic:

```
    val PCMD_API_GET_INFO = byteArrayOf(
        0xAB.toByte(),
        0x01.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte()
    )
```